# C++ post-increment: objects vs primitive types

Tags: c++, overloading, post-increment

We cannot use pre-increment on rvalues:

```
int i = 0;
int j = ++i++; // Compile error: lvalue required
```

If we define a class:

```
class A
{
public:
    A & operator++()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    A operator++(int)
    {
        A temp(*this);
        return temp;
    }
};
```

then we can compile:

```
A i;
A j = ++i++;
```

What is the different between A object and int data type that

```
j = ++i++;
```

compiles with A but not with int?

Comment: `++i++` is one of those statements you really don't want to see in your code.

Comment: Class operators are simply functions with syntax sugar, just as you expect `B{}.f()` to compile, so would `++B{}`.

Comment: @tadman Agree and I want to design a class that prevents ++i++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when overloaded operators are defined as member functions, they follow some semantics which are more related to calling a member function, not to the behavior of the built-in operator.  Note that by default, if we declare a non-static member function like:

```
class X {
public:
    void f();
    X g();
};
```

then we can call it on both lvalue and rvalue class type expressions:

```
X().f();   // okay, the X object is prvalue
X x;
x.f();     // okay, the X object is lvalue
x.g().f(); // also okay, x.g() is prvalue
```

When overload resolution for an operator expression selects a member function, the expression is changed to be just a call to that member function, so it follows the same rules:

```
++A(); // okay, transformed to A().operator++(), called on prvalue
A a;
++a;   // okay, transformed to a.operator++(), called on lvalue
++a++; // also technically okay, transformed to a.operator++(0).operator++(),
       // a.operator++(0) is a prvalue.
```

This sort of non-equivalence between built-in operators and overloaded operators also happens with the left subexpression of assignment: the pointless statement `std::string() = std::string();` is legal, but the statement `int() = int();` is not legal.

But you noted in a comment "I want to design a class that prevents `++a++`".  There are at least two ways to do that.

First, you could use a non-member operator instead of a member.  Most overloaded operators can be implemented as either a member or non-member, where the class type needs to be added as an additional first parameter type of the non-member function.  For example, if `a` has class type, the expression `++a` will attempt to find a function as if it were `a.operator++()` and also a function as if it were `operator++(a)`; and the expression `a++` will look for functions for the expressions `a.operator++(0)` or `operator++(a, 0)`.

(This pattern of trying both ways does not apply to functions named `operator=`, `operator()`, `operator[]`, or `operator->`, because they may only be defined as non-static member functions, never as non-members.  Functions named `operator new`, `operator new[]`, `operator delete`, or `operator delete[]`, plus user-defined literal functions whose names start like `operator ""`, follow entirely different sets of rules.)

And when the class argument matches a real function parameter, instead of the "implicit object parameter" of a non-static member function, the type of reference used in the parameter, if any, controls as usual whether an argument can be an lvalue, rvalue, or either.

```
class B {
public:
    // Both increment operators are valid only on lvalues.
    friend B& operator++(B& b) {
        // Some internal increment logic.
        return b;
    }
    friend B operator++(B& b, int) {
        B temp(b);
        ++temp;
        return temp;
    }
};

void test_B() {
    ++B(); // Error: Tried operator++(B()), can't pass
           // rvalue B() to B& parameter
    B b;
    ++b;   // Okay: Transformed to operator++(b), b is lvalue
    ++b++; // Error: Tried operator++(operator++(b,0)), but
           // operator++(b,0) is prvalue and can't pass to B& parameter
}
```

Another way is to add ref-qualifiers to member functions, which were added to the language in the C++11 version as a specific way of controlling whether a member function's implicit object argument must be an lvalue or rvalue:

```
class C {
public:
    C& operator++() & {
        // Some internal increment logic.
        return *this;
    }
    C operator++(int) & {
        C temp(*this);
        ++temp;
        return temp;
    }
};
```

Notice the `&` between the parameter list and the start of the body.  This restricts the function to only accept an lvalue of type `C` (or something that implicitly converts to a `C&` reference) as the implicit object argument, similarly to how a `const` in the same spot allows the implicit object argument to have type `const C`.  If you wanted a function to require an lvalue but allow that lvalue to optionally be `const`, the `const` comes before the ref-qualifier: `void f() const &;`

```
void test_C() {
    ++C(); // Error: Tried C().operator++(), doesn't allow rvalue C()
           // as implicit object parameter
    C c;
    ++c;   // Okay: Transformed to c.operator++(), c is lvalue
    ++c++; // Error: Tried c.operator++(0).operator++(), but
           // c.operator++(0) is prvalue, not allowed as implicit object
           // parameter of operator++().
}
```

To get `operator=` to act more like it does for a scalar type, we can't use a non-member function, because the language only allows member `operator=` declarations, but the ref-qualifier will similarly work.  You're even allowed to use the `= default;` syntax to have the compiler generate the body, even though the function isn't declared in exactly the same way an implicitly-declared assignment function would have been.

```
class D {
public:
    D() = default;
    D(const D&) = default;
    D(D&&) = default;
    D& operator=(const D&) & = default;
    D& operator=(D&&) & = default;
};

void test_D() {
    D() = D(); // Error: implicit object argument (left-hand side) must
               // be an lvalue
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It … just is. There are a few constraints that apply only to primitive types and not class types (well, you've found the most obvious one!).

It is largely because operators for built-in types are one thing, whereas for classes they are just member functions in disguise and therefore a completely different beast.

Is this confusing? I don't know; maybe.

Is there a really compelling reason for it? I don't know; possibly not. There's a certain inertia with primitive types: why change something that was in C just because you're introducing classes? What is the benefit of permitting this? On the other hand, would it not be overly strict to ban it for classes, whose implementation of `operator++` could do something that, as the language designer, you haven't thought of?